# PHP - Changing HTML text with variable from MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a website and I've got up to a bit now where I want text on the homepage to change, depending on whether or not the user is logged in. Before doing this, I wrapped the text in a div class, which has allowed me to configure how it looks inside a css file. By default, if the user is not logged in, the index.html should display "iBPBuyer, Amazing Deals & Prices." and when the user is logged in, it should then change that text to a simple welcome message, stating their name afterwards, but I cannot seem to get it working.

```
<?php
    require("includes/application_top.php"); 
    require("includes/site_header.php");
    require("includes/application_bottom.php"); 

if($_SESSION['id']) {
    echo '<div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>Welcome,<br> $_SESSION['first'].</h1>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
    </div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>iBPBuyer,<br> Amazing Deals &amp; Prices.</h1>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
    </div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: DO you `session_start()` anywhere in those required scripts??? If not you need to do it in this code

Comment: What is not working?...are you getting an error or something?...can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Logged part should be:

```
echo '<div class="hero-text-box">
    <h1>Welcome,<br>' . $_SESSION['first'] . '</h1>
</div>  
<div class="row">
</div>';
```

So, it's just correct concatenation technique.

Comment: Ha... very probably

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, thank you very much, pretty much my first time tackling PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code

```
$welcome = "iBPBuyer,<br> Amazing Deals &amp; Prices.";

if($_SESSION['id']) {
    $welcome = 'Welcome,<br> ' . $_SESSION['first'];
}

echo '<div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>' . $welcome . '</h1>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
    </div>';
```